# Pandas replace column value under condition

Tags: pandas, replace

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1., 2., 3., 4.], 'B' : [4., 3., 2., 1.], 'C' : [pd.NaT,8,pd.NaT,0]})
df
```

[image]

And I would like to change the column B to the value of C everytime that C is different from NaT. The final result would be the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['B'] = df['C'].combine_first(df['B'])
print (df)
     A  B    C
0  1.0  4  NaT
1  2.0  8    8
2  3.0  2  NaT
3  4.0  0    0
```

And if need `float`s:

```
df['B'] = df['C'].combine_first(df['B']).astype(df['B'].dtype)
print (df)
     A    B    C
0  1.0  4.0  NaT
1  2.0  8.0    8
2  3.0  2.0  NaT
3  4.0  0.0    0
```

Or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df['C'].notnull(), df['C'])
print (df)
     A  B    C
0  1.0  4  NaT
1  2.0  8    8
2  3.0  2  NaT
3  4.0  0    0
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['C'].notnull(), df['C'], df['B'])
print (df)
     A  B    C
0  1.0  4  NaT
1  2.0  8    8
2  3.0  2  NaT
3  4.0  0    0
```

Answer (score 2):

`pd.Series.fillna`

```
df.B = df.C.fillna(df.B)
df

     A    B    C
0  1.0  4.0  NaT
1  2.0  8.0    8
2  3.0  2.0  NaT
3  4.0  0.0    0
```

---

`pd.DataFrame.where`

```
df.B = df.B.where(df.C.isnull(), df.C).astype(df.B.dtype)
df

     A    B    C
0  1.0  4.0  NaT
1  2.0  8.0    8
2  3.0  2.0  NaT
3  4.0  0.0    0
```